# Too many Activities being started when launching an Android Application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am confirming about creating activity.

My Manifest.xml is like this :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
 <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can see property `action android:name=` property is `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` and 
`category android:name=` is `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` for all activities.

When the application starts up, it calls **FirstActivity**.
Then calls useless Activity such as ThirdActivity or SecondActivity.

In this case, is my `manifest.xml` correct?
Or, do I need to set another property to Second and Third activity?
If so, what is that?

I wonder `manifest.xml` file is right for my case.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this config:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".FirstActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
 <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Ok. thanks. Do second and third Activity look as child activity ?

Comment: Yes, you can start them latter using Intents.

Answer (score 1):

Think of an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) as message used to start an `Activity` to do something.  So I can create an `Intent` to view a web page and an application with an Activity which knows how to view a web page - most likely the browser - can intercept his Intent as act on it.

You tell Android which Activities can act on which Intents using the `<intent-filter>` part of your Manifest.

The [`MAIN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN) `Intent` is a special one.  This is sent to an application when it is launched and basically it says "Go!"  So the `Activity` which shoud be displayed first needs to intercept this by having a correctly defined `<intent-filter>`.

As you had all three Activities with `MAIN` in their filter they all responded to the request to start your application.  So you should have that `<intent-filter>` only for `FirstActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the other problems with using 
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` for more than one activity is that the Phone's launcher menu will display more than one icon...

**From the docs:**

> CATEGORY_LAUNCHER     The activity can
>   be the initial activity of a task and
>   is listed in the top-level application
>   launcher.